# Remove whitespace from json using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a simple JSON like this:

```
{
  "enums" : [{"someName" : "  someValue   ", etc.. }]
}
```

Sometimes,  someValue has whitespace in it.  (ie. "  someValue  ")

I can't seem to get how to SET each value back to the node.  I have this:

```
        JsonNode values = root.get("enumValues");
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodes = values.getFields();
        while (nodes.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>) nodes.next();
             //  what do I do here?
        }
```

I know that JsonNodes are imutable,  but how do I get the JsonObjects?  <String, JsonObject>  wont work.

I want to be able to parse this as an object (I eventually want to make in recursive for more complex JSON,  but one thing at a time) so that when I
print the JSON out it would look like this:

```
{
  "enums" : [{"someName" : "someValue", etc.. }]
}
```

Comment: what are you doing exactly?

Comment: @deadshot  Looking to strip whitespaces.  I want "   somevalue  "   to be "somevalue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a JSON example

```
{
    "enums" : [{"someName" : "  someValue   ", "a": " b "}]
}
```

you can do it like this:
(I also added some code to read the JSON input and to print the JSON output,
and fixed some flaws in your code to make it compilable)

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
File file = new File("example.json");
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readValue(file, JsonNode.class);
    
ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) root.get("enums");
ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) arrayNode.get(0);      
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodes = objectNode.fields();
while (nodes.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = nodes.next();
    if (entry.getValue().isTextual()) {
        String s = entry.getValue().asText();  // get string from JSON node
        s = s.trim();                          // remove leading/trailing space
        objectNode.put(entry.getKey(), s);     // put the string back into JSON node
    }
} 

objectMapper.writeValue(System.out, root);
```

Then you get the JSON output

```
{"enums":[{"someName":"someValue","a":"b"}]}
```